# Is it possible to make pagination and search on Ignited DataTable if bServerSide is set to false

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, datatable, pagination

I'm a newbie and is doing my school project.

Is it possible to make pagination and search on Ignited DataTable if bServerSide is set to false? If I set bServerSide: false, Search does work, but pagination doesn't. but I do bServserSide: true, pagination works but search doesn't.

my model:

```
function projectDT(){
            $this->datatables->select('ProjectId, ProjectName, ProjectLocation, Status')
            ->add_column('Action', get_buttons('project/viewProject/$1','project/editProject/$1', '$1'), 'ProjectId')
            ->where ('IsActive',1)
            ->from('project')
            ->join('status','status.StatusId=project.StatusId','left');

            echo $this->datatables->generate();
        }
```

controller:

```
function viewProjectJSON(){ 
            $projectList = $this->projectmodel->projectDT(); 
            return $projectList;
        }
```

js:

```
var oTable = $('#projectDT').dataTable( { //#projectDT is the TABLE na atong i-convert to datatable
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": 'http://localhost:81/ORPS/project/viewProjectJSON', //source sa data
        "bJQueryUI": false,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayStart ": 10,
        "oLanguage" : {
            "sProcessing": "<img src='http://localhost:81/ORPS/images/loading-icons/loading3.gif'>"
        },
        'fnServerData': function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback)
        {
         $.ajax
         ({
            'dataType': 'json',
            'type'    : 'POST',
            'url'     : sSource,
            'data'    : aoData,
            'success' : fnCallback
         });
        },
    } );
```

Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: I've never used Ignited DataTable however, by the looks of it, you need to tell jquery DataTables which columns are searchable using `"bSearchable" : true` inside `aoColumnDefs`. Have a look at the [DataTables columns page](http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns)

Comment: thanks for the idea. but it doesn't work